# Jython variable to Java Beanshell in ODI

Tags: jython, beanshell, oracle-data-integrator

I have the variable `total_lines` on a jython command that I needs to be accessed on the refreshing command of a ODI variable.

```
with open('file.txt') as file_name:
        for total_lines, line in enumerate(file_name):
            pass
        print total_lines
total_lines += 1
```

For this I thought of passing it through a Java Beanshell variable using <@ @>. Like so:
in the jython command:

```
<@int totallines = total_lines; @>
```

in the refreshing command:

```
select '<@=totallines@>' from dual;
```

Is this possible? How can I attribute a jython variable to a beanshell variable? What are my alternatives?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you must execute the first calculation of your variable with java bean shell inside tags

`<@ for ... totallines += 1 ... @>`

instead of Jython. Then, your refreshing command will work.